# Reverse proxy using ARR (Application Request Routing) - POST method does not work

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, arr

We are trying to setup a reverse proxy mechanism using ARR (Application Request Routing) and URL Rewrite. The rewriting is working fine when we use GET Method request
but when we send Post for method with this content type (x-form-urlencoded) request, ARR does not return any response. How can I solve this problem?

```xml
 <rewrite>
      <rules>
            <rule name="InboundGeneral" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:29341/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
            </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: can anybody htlp me ?

Comment: "not return any response" means what in terms of HTTP Codes? 400? 500? or does it abort? Do you see something in failed request tracing?

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but I found it when I was looking for a solution to the same problem I had.

I have discovered that the problem was due to a conflict between ARR and ASP.net MVC running on the same site. It turns out, that if you process request parameters for whatever reason in your main site (e.g. filters, or global.asax) it will clear out the post parameters in the request sent by ARR, and hence resulting in a timeout.

You can solve it in one of two ways:

1. Put ARR in a separate process (if you can)
2. Or make sure whatever filter you have checks the path being used in
   ARR and avoid touching the request parameters.